# Slow moving folder with a lot of files from Windows to WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

## Problem

I move folder with a lot files inside by using this command on WSL:

```
 mv --verbose /mnt/c/Users/FreePhoenix/Documents/Programming/object-to-links-async-converter.zip ./
```

## Additional Information

I use `--verbose` to see is there actually something happens and it is! But I have been waiting 10 minutes and I have not saw finish - it still was moving it
Without `--verbose` I have the same result

## Question

Is there another faster way to move that folder to WSL?

## Environment

Note that version of my WSL is 2:

```
PS C:\Users\FreePhoenix> wsl --list --verbose
  NAME      STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu    Running         2
```

Comment: According to the command you've shared, you're moving a single `*.zip` file (not a "_folder with a lot of files_")... if the file is very large, and you're moving it between filesystems (as suggested by the full path for the source), then it could well take a while to complete.

Comment: next time use rsync: ```rsync -aP /mnt/c/Users/FreePhoenix/Documents/Programming/object-to-links-async-converter.zip ./```

Comment: @Attie uh, it is double-edged sword xD

Comment: @hanshenrik Why should I use rsync instead of mv?

Comment: @FreePhoenix rsync gives you realtime `MB/s` copy speed information, mv doesn't. rsync is also smart-ish, if you cancel your `mv` command right now and issue the rsync command above, rsync will check how far mv got, and continue where mv left off, it will not start from scratch. try it! :)

Comment: @hanshenrik That is some golden info! Thank you, will definitely use rsync from now on.

Answer (score 5):

For information see the post
[Why is WSL extremely slow when compared with native Windows NPM/Yarn processing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68972448/why-is-wsl-extremely-slow-when-compared-with-native-windows-npm-yarn-processing)

The message in the post is that this is a problem of WSL2, which is
a regression compared to WSL1. I would theorize that this is because
WSL1 executes directly under Windows, while WSL2 executes under Hyper-V.

Already in Microsoft's
[Comparing WSL 1 and WSL 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions)
the '*Performance across the OS file systems*' is explicitly
admitted by Microsoft to be worse in WSL2 *by design*:

[image: Comparison of WS1 and WSL2 from Comparing WSL 1 and WSL 2]

Note that this is not a new problem. It was already signaled in the
bug report
[[wsl2] filesystem performance is much slower than wsl1 in /mnt #4197](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4197),
which dates from 2019.

As the problem wasn't addressed by Microsoft in 5 years, there is not
much chance that it will ever be corrected.

The poster has minimized his interaction in WSL2 with both the
file-systems of WSL and Windows by packing his folder in an
archive and transferring the archive as one file, then
unpacking it in WSL2.

Answer (score 3):

### 1. Archive Your Folder (Choose One Option)

#### Option A: Using the GUI

[image: Archiving through GUI]

#### Option B: Using PowerShell

```
Compress-Archive -Path C:\SOURCE\PATH\TO\YOUR\FILES -Update -DestinationPath C:\DESTINATION\PATH\ZIPPEDFILE.zip
```

Make sure to replace the paths with your source and destination locations.

### 2. Move the Archive to WSL

1. **Enter WSL**: Type `wsl` in the Command Prompt to enter your WSL environment.
2. **Move the Archive**: Use this command to move the archive from your Windows directory to a location in WSL:

```bash
mv /mnt/c/PATH/OF/SOURCE/ARCHIVE ~/PATH/TO/DESTINATION/ARCHIVE
```

Replace the paths with the relevant locations.

*Note*: In WSL, your C: drive is typically mounted at `/mnt/c`.

### 3. Unzip the Archive in WSL

Note that this step uses `apt` which is Debian package manager and if you use non-debian OS on WSL you should use your package manager

#### 3.1 Install Unzip (if not already installed)

Run these commands:

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install unzip
```

#### 3.2 Unzip the Archive

Use:

```bash
unzip ~/PATH/TO/DESTINATION/ARCHIVE
```

Or, to a specific directory:

```bash
unzip ~/PATH/TO/DESTINATION/ARCHIVE -d /path/to/extract/folder
```

*Note*: To prevent overwriting, add the `-n` option:

```bash
unzip -n ~/PATH/TO/DESTINATION/ARCHIVE -d /path/to/extract/folder
```